# Routerlinkactive option not working angular7

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have `studentlist`, `studentdetails` and `student` components. From `studentlist`, If I click on one of row it opens the `studentdetails` component with sidebar component.

I want to retain an active link of sidebar component tab when either `studentdetails` and `student` component loads.

More specifically I have three routes. From sidebar component tab, you can go in path2 and then path3
Path links:
path1 : `locahost:4200/studentlist`
path2 : `locahost:4200/studentdetails/{id}`
path3:  `locahost:4200/student/{id}/{teacherid}`

Component1: `studentdetails`
Path: `/studentdetails/{id}`

After clicking on edit button present on `studentdetails` page, it opens up `student` component.

Component2: `student`
Path: `/student/{id}/{teacherid}`

Could you please guide how should I keep sidebar component tab - 'student' active when I navigate to the path: `/student/{id}/{teacherid}`

Adding snippets of `ts` and `html` files respectively

```ts
1) studentlist.ts

studentDetailsRouteUrl: string = 'student-details';

2)studentdetails.ts

 actionUrl:string =  'student'

3)sidebarcomponent.ts
studentDetailsRoute = 'student-details'
lblStudent = 'STUDENT'
```

```html
1) studentlist.html

<tr *ngFor="let studnet of studentList">
   <td>
      <a [routerLink]="[studentDetailsRouteUrl]" [queryParams]="{ currentView: 'studentdetails'}"
      [routerLinkActive]="['active']"     
      [state]="{studentdetails: student, studentid:stundet.studentid}" >
      {{student.studentname}}
      </a>
   </td>
</tr>

2) studentdetails.html

<button [routerLinkActive]="['active']"  
[routerLink]="[ actionUrl, studentid, teacherid]" 
[queryParams]="{ currentView: 'editDetails'}">
Edit Button
</button>

3)sidebarcomponent.html 
<ul>
   <li>
      <a  [routerLink]="[ studentDetailsRoute]"
      [routerLinkActive]="['active']"
      [queryParams]="{ currentView: 'studentdetails'}"> {{lblStudent}} 
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>

4)student.html

code related to edit functionality and update in database.
```

Comment: can you please provide code ?

Comment: Added. Please note : from student list component, we are loading sidebarcomponent and studentDetails component. From studentDetails component(though Edit button), we are loading student component

Comment: More specifically I have three routes. From sidebar component tab, you can go in path2 and then path3
path1 : locahost:4200/studentlist
path2 : locahost:4200/studentdetails/{id}
path3: locahost:4200/student/{id}/{teacherid}